# How can I add an user to existing Google App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an App Engine project to which I want to add another user, so she will have access to see it and also deploy to it.

I've tried to add her in IAM but she doesn't see the project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to grant her deploy permissions, you should grant her, at least, [App Engine Deployer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#predefined_app_engine_roles) in IAM. You may need to grant also the Storage Admin role if that person is planning on using `gcloud` commands, which is most likely for deployments.